# в чем заключается ошибка при работе с puppet7 и как ее исправить?

Tags: linux, puppet

Выполняю лабораторную работу, в ходе которой изучаю puppet7, и при выполнении команды

> sudo puppetserver ca list --all

Я получил следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Во первых, я не совсем понимаю, куда он лезет и зачем
- Во вторых, что
  посоветуете здесь сделать для решения данной проблемы, я с клиента
  отправил запрос на подключение к серверу и не могу его принять из-за этой проблемы,
  заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну а порт `8140` на хосте `puppet` открыт? А сам хост резолвится?

Answer (score 0):

Все, проблема решилась, там дело быдл не в порте, а просто в файле /etc/hosts, когда указывал адрес сервера не написал "puppet", а когда написал то все заработало